# Update version in package.json with github release

Tags: javascript, github, npm, version, github-actions

I need to update the version number in my package.json file when I release it from github. Is there any method for that also can I set the newly created tag version as version number in package.json

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-release

Answer (score 3):

There are some libraries that automate this process. One of them is release-it.

https://github.com/release-it/release-it

This package automatically bumps up the version number in the package.json and create a new brnach/tag. It also automates pushing to NPM, creating change log, cd/ci etc.

```
  "name": "my-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "release": "release-it"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "release-it": "*"
  }
}
```

then

`npm run release`

or

`npm run release -- minor --ci`

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I need to execte it automatically when i click new release on github. Is there any way for that

Comment: Have you tried using release-it within a github action? I'm just trying to set this up now.